# My .NET Core 5.0 web application is not working after publishing it. Error "Unhandled exception. System.TypeInitializationException: "

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have developed a .Net Core 5.0 Console application using Visual Studio 2019 + Windows Server 2012 R2. then i Publish the console application as a Self-Contained application >> i moved the Published files to our live server, but when i run the .exe file on live server i got this exception:-

```
Unhandled exception. System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'ServiceDeskSharePointIntegration.Program' threw an exception.
 ---> System.FormatException: Could not parse the JSON file.
 ---> System.Text.Json.JsonReaderException: 'M' is an invalid escapable characte
r within a JSON string. The string should be correctly escaped. LineNumber: 2 |
BytePositionInLine: 46.
   at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowJsonReaderException(Utf8JsonReader& json
, ExceptionResource resource, Byte nextByte, ReadOnlySpan`1 bytes)
   at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.ConsumeStringAndValidate(ReadOnlySpan`1 da
ta, Int32 idx)
   at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.ConsumeString()
   at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.ConsumeValue(Byte marker)
   at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.ReadSingleSegment()
   at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.Read()
   at System.Text.Json.JsonDocument.Parse(ReadOnlySpan`1 utf8JsonSpan, JsonReade
rOptions readerOptions, MetadataDb& database, StackRowStack& stack)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonDocument.Parse(ReadOnlyMemory`1 utf8Json, JsonReaderO
ptions readerOptions, Byte[] extraRentedBytes)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonDocument.Parse(ReadOnlyMemory`1 json, JsonDocumentOpt
ions options)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonDocument.Parse(String json, JsonDocumentOptions optio
ns)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json.JsonConfigurationFileParser.ParseS
tream(Stream input)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json.JsonConfigurationFileParser.Parse(
Stream input)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json.JsonConfigurationProvider.Load(Str
eam stream)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json.JsonConfigurationProvider.Load(Str
eam stream)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationProvider.Load(Boolean
reload)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationProvider.HandleExcepti
on(ExceptionDispatchInfo info)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationProvider.Load(Boolean
reload)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationProvider.Load()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationRoot..ctor(IList`1 provide
rs)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilder.Build()
   at ServiceDeskSharePointIntegration.Program..cctor() in C:\Users\m**\source\repos\ServiceDeskSharePointIntegration\ServiceDeskSharePointIntegratio
n\Program.cs:line 21
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at ServiceDeskSharePointIntegration.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\**\source\repos\ServiceDeskSharePointIntegration\ServiceDeskSharePoin
tIntegration\Program.cs:line 80
```

now inside Visual Studio the console application is working fine.

My appsetting.json looks as follow:-

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "ConnectionString": "Server=1**1\Manageengine;Database=ServiceDesk;Trusted_Connection=True;User ID=ad-***\tmsdb.****;Password=$***"
  },
  "SP": {
    "SiteURL": "https://****infra.sharepoint.com/",
    "SiteURL2": "https://****infra.sharepoint.com/sites/customerservicekb/",
    "UFSNotification": "feedback@***.net",
    "SendEmail": "true"
  },

  "ServiceDesk": {

    "Field": "udf_fields.udf_pick_35401",
    "Technician_Key": "6***-3EC7-4D8C-***2",
    "APIURL": "https://localhost/"
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you read the error message _Could not parse the JSON file_?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski but not sure why ? it is working well on visual studio? are they referring to the appsetting.json file? which is already included in the published files..

Comment: @johnGu - that or something like it looks likely. It says something about `M` being unescapable. Maybe you have a `\M` somewhere in the file?

Comment: I suspect that they're using different JSON files based on the environment name - typically you'd have appSettings.json, appSettings.Development.json and appSettings.Production.json or something like that.

Comment: @Kit inside my connection string i have this `"Server=1**1\Manageengine` which include the IP address of the server and the instant name of the DB .. so could the \M cause the issue? i added my appsetting.json inside my question

Comment: @JonSkeet so how i can tell?

Comment: Why i got 2 down votes? what need to be done...

Comment: That is invalid JSON, your text editor should show that surely? The error message even tells you exactly where the problem is, line 2, character 46.

Comment: "so how i can tell" - you would look at the files used in production. And now that you've shown the file, we can see the error...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your connection string is escaped improperly.

Change this

```
    "ConnectionString": "Server=1**1\Manageengine;Database=ServiceDesk;Trusted_Connection=True;User ID=ad-***\tmsdb.****;Password=$***"
```

to this

```
    "ConnectionString": "Server=1**1\\Manageengine;Database=ServiceDesk;Trusted_Connection=True;User ID=ad-***\\tmsdb.****;Password=$***"
```

You need an extra `\` for two parts of that string. The `\M` and the `\t` need to be `\\M` and `\\t` respectively.

Comment: you are 100% correct.. it is working well now.. but i copied the connection string from a regular .net (non-core) console application which use to work well

Comment: @johnGu It may be that the original used a less strict (and/or incorrectly implemented) parser.

Comment: @johnGu: Was that copied from an XML file rather than a JSON file, by any chance? XML doesn't escape backslashes... you always need to be really careful when copying data from one file format to another.